# LDR issue interfacing with ADC

Tags: ldr

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff07sW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to read the voltage values of LDR (0-5V)but my desire range is less ( 1-3V)  through ADC of 10-bit,but i am getting Clipped values , what can be the issue.. ??

Comment: What ADC,with what reference voltage?

Comment: How can we know the issue if you DON'T show us the circuit ?

Comment: Even with the circuit, I don't really understand where you are having issues.

Comment: I cant see the amplified output on CRO , is my ckt correct or need any correction ??

Comment: This question is still lacking some crucial information. What LDR are you using, how is your op-amp powered. What do you see on the output of the op-amp. And just out of curiosity, what does CRO and CKT stand for?

Comment: Your circuit ("ckt") diagram doesn't mention the voltage of the power supply for the LM324.  That really needs to be there.

Comment: That said, your comments and the diagram make it clear that the problem is **not** the ADC, but the circuit before it.  Please edit your question to make it match the real problem.

Comment: That you are trying to read a voltage with the ADC is relevant, and belongs in the question.  That the error occurs at the buffer is the real problem, though.

Answer (score 2):

You have a 1 to 3 volt signal, and are amplifying it by 20.  That would result in a 20 to 60 volt signal if the amplifier were capable of that.  It should be no surprise that whatever A/D this signal is being presented to is clipping.

The simplest answer is to reduce the gain so that the maximum signal of interest is just below the top end of the A/D range.  If the A/D range is 0-3 volts, then you don't need any amplification at all.

A 1-3 V signal into a 0-3 V A/D will use ⅔ of the A/D range.  For a 10 bit A/D, that leaves you with a resolution of 682.  If that's not good enough, use a 12 bit A/D.  That would give you a resolution of 2730.

Comment: Yes...10-bit ADC will have 4.8mv resolution and 12-bit will have 1.22mv resolution and i need values as much as i can between 1 to 3V..I will try 12 bit ADC . Thanks

Comment: plz clear my one doubt that, if i limit my ADC input to 1-3 V and ADC having resolution of 4.8mV , then in that case ADC output should not b clipped bcz ADC now has a good range (1-3V) and it should give good no. of samples of each 4.8mV as output...?????

Answer (score 1):

An LDR (light dependent resistor) does not output a voltage. One would always use the LDR in a circuit. 
The easiest circuit is a resistive divider, as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2I8o1m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By choosing the resistor R1 correctly you can make the output voltage to the ADC within your range of 0-3V. 
Take the dark-resistance and make de divider based on that. Any light will decrease the resistance of the LDR and thus make the signal output to the ADC a lower voltage.

Comment: Yes i m using the same ckt . I am using the LDR+LED setup for my project . I need to amplify the output from LDR to be process through ADC bcz of this clipping issue , for this m using non inverting amplifier but when m seeing this on CRO then it just showing a DC output ... so plz tell .???

Comment: Hopw can i amplify my LDR output ..??

Comment: You know that clipping means that it is either showing the maximum or minimum value that the ADC can output? You won't solve that by using an amplifier nor by changing the ADC. Just calculate the correct resistor value and put a reference for your ADC with a sensible voltage level.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable reply , could you please more elaborate this ..?? i mean correct resistor in what sense and i am using 5V reference voltage for adc..

Comment: dark resistance of my LDR is 2.5megaohms and in intense light it is 300ohm...